# how to filter depending on a value after grouping by in spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

let's say I have the following data Frame :

```
val a=Seq(("aa","b",1),("aa","c",5),("aa","d",0),("xx","y",5),("z","zz",9),("z","b",12)).toDF("name","tag","num").show
+----+---+---+
|name|tag|num|
+----+---+---+
|  aa|  b|  1|
|  aa|  c|  5|
|  aa|  d|  0|
|  xx|  y|  5|
|   z| zz|  9|
|   z|  b| 12|
+----+---+---+
```

I want to filter this dataFrame so that :

for each group of data (grouped by name) if the column tag have the value 'b' I'll take the max value of the num column , otherwise I ignore the row

here is the out put that I want to have :

```
+----+---+---+
|name|tag|num|
+----+---+---+
|  aa|  c|  5|
|   z|  b| 12|
+----+---+---+
```

**Explanation**

- the group of rows having the name ='aa' hase a row in which the value of tag == 'b', thus I'm taking the max of num of this group which is 5.
- the group of rows having the name ='xx' hase no row in which the value of tag == 'b',thus it w
- the group of rows having the name ='z' hase a row in which the value of tag == 'b',thus I'm taking the max of num of this group which is 12.

Comment: you can create a UserDefinedAggregateFunction in Spark.

Comment: its not recommanded to use UDF unless there is no other solution, I'm trying to use window, I think it can help

Comment: whatever you wish ... just saying but in that case you'll need an aggregate nevertheless. good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
val df=Seq(("aa","b",1),("aa","c",5),("aa","d",0),("xx","y",5),("z","zz",9),("z","b",12)).toDF("name","tag","num")
df.createOrReplaceTempView("tab")

val res = spark.sql(""" with tw as (select t1.name, max(t1.num) as max_val
                          from tab t1 
                         where t1.name in (select distinct t2.name 
                                             from tab t2
                                            where t2.tag = 'b'
                                          )
                      group by t1.name )
                      select distinct tz.name, tz.tag, tz.num
                        from tab tz, tw
                       where tz.name = tw.name
                         and tz.num  = tw.max_val
                   """) 
res.show(false)
```

Comment: thank you for your solution, I figure out an other one using window : 
` val w=Window.partitionBy("name")`

Comment: more than 1 way leads to Rome...but I do not see the partitionBy as the obvious use case here... the answer is correct, though.

Comment: yeah your are right, more over, the window way is way complicated